# what is Regex pattern for html tag in java or android?

Tags: java, android, regex

i have this tag as input tag:

```
<a href="controller.jsp?sid=127490C88DB5&R=35144" class="11-link-dkred-bold"><b>Mr. John Q. Anderson&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MBA 1977 E</a>
```

in this i want get the value

**Mr. John Q. Anderson   MBA 1977 E**

wat is patten value for this in regex?

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing HTML. Use an HTML Parser. Moreover, what are you trying to accomplish that requires extracting that information?

Comment: the best regex is `Pattern.compile("Simply don't!");` ;)

Comment: Is the example tag all that is in the String, or does the String you are matching against hold an entire page of HTML that includes this tag?  If the string contains an entire page's HTML, is there more than one occurrence of the data you are trying to extract in the HTML?  Have you made any attempts to solve this yet?  If so what are the issues you are having?

Comment: Highly recommend reading through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags accepted answer.  Just don't do it.

Comment: Haha! Just read that answer. Is that the most upvoted answer on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a **Very Bad Idea**<sup>TM</sup> to parse HTML using regular expressions since it is not a regular language. You are better off running this through tidy (to clean it up), and then using an XML parser or use XPath.

Otherwise, the matching pattern with captures is:

```
<.*?>\([^<]+\)</.*?>
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed that your HTML is not well-formed! You don't have a closing `</b>` tag. The regex I gave you will only work if you one tag wrapping your text. It won't work for your example. Assuming you will always have a `<b>...</b>` tag inside you can do:

```
<.*?><b>\([^<]+\)</b></.*?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using NekoHTML or some alternative, see e.g. http://www.benmccann.com/blog/java-html-parsing-library-comparison/

If you want to parse it yourself, use ANTLR or JavaCC or something similar. To do it right, you need a powerful grammar.